# std::function with template, type problem, no matching function for call

Tags: c++, templates, types, auto, std-function

I have a function defined this way:

```
template <size_t SIZE>
double MyFun(std::function<double(std::array<double,SIZE>&)> f, std::array<double,SIZE> &x, std::array<double,SIZE> &y){
   instructions;
}
```

and another function, which should be the argument of the previous, defined like this:

```
double MyFun2(std::array<double,3> &var){
  instructions;
}
```

If I try to call "MyFun" like this:

```
    double something;
    std::array<double,3> var = {...};
    std::array<double,3> var2 = {...};
    something = MyFun(MyFun2, var, var2);
```

I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MyFun(double (&)(std::array<double, 3>&), std::array<double, 3>&, std::array<double, 3>&)’
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<double(std::array<double, SIZE>&)>’ and ‘double (*)(std::array<double, 3>&)’
```

Moreover, if I try to store "MyFun2" in a variable with "auto"

```
  auto function = MyFun2;
```

the type given to "function" is:

```
  double (*function)(std::array<double, 3UL> &var)
```

and I can't use "function" as a parameter for MyFun aswell.
The only solution I've found is to somewhat cast "MyFun2" in the right type by specifying it:

```
  double something;
  std::array<double,3> var = {...};
  std::array<double,3> var2 = {...};

  std::function<double(std::array<double,3>&)> function = MyFun2;
  something = MyFun(function, var, var2);
```

This way, passing "function" as the first parameter of "MyFun" works.
But why do I have such an ambiguity and I can't call MyFun by just typing MyFun2 as the first parameter? And why auto won't figure out the "right" type?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `no matching function for call to...` error `std::function` doesn't have deduction guides for deducing the signature of a function pointer.

When you do this:

```
auto function = MyFun2;
```

The function, `MyFun2` is decayed to a function pointer. It doesn't make sense to store the value of a function in a variable because, well, what is the value of a function? It's a block of machine instructions. Why would you ever want to copy that around? The language assumes that you won't so a function is decayed to a function pointer. The above is equivalent to this:

```
double (*function)(std::array<double, 3> &var) = MyFun2;
```

You found one solution to the error and that is to construct a `std::function` from the function pointer directly. Another solution would be to avoid `std::function` altogether.

```
template <size_t SIZE>
double MyFun(double (*f)(std::array<double, SIZE>&), std::array<double, SIZE> &x, std::array<double, SIZE> &y){
   instructions;
}
```

So now your original example works

```
something = MyFun(MyFun2, var, var2);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain! I understood the problem! In this case I'll use function pointers :)

Answer (score 3):

Template argument deduction works by matching exactly on the parameters you pass in. It does not take conversion into consideration.

Since passing `MyFun` is the same as passing a function pointer, and your template is looking for a `std::function` the deduction fails.

The idiomatic approach is to accept any callable in the template, without worrying about the signature. Since you will call that callable in your template, if the signature doesn't match you will get a compile time error anyway.

```
template <typename Func, size_t SIZE>
double MyFun(F f, std::array<double,SIZE> &x, std::array<double,SIZE> &y){
   // go ahead and use f(x, y); for example
}
```

This approach has the additional benefit that you are not limited to one type of callable. We could pass in a function pointer, a std::function, a Functor. Anything that support the syntax `f(...);`

Answer (score 2):

In order to create an object of an `std::function`, you need to use `std::bind(&MyFun2, std::placeholders::_1)`. For a reference [address cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) .

There are some issues with your code also. `std::funcion` is rather large, and in x64 will occupy 64 bytes, so copying it would not be the best solution. You either pass it as a const reference, or as r-value reference for RAII purposes.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#include <numeric>

// typedef Alias for convinence
template <size_t sz>
using Wrapped_t = std::function<double(const std::array<double, sz>&)>;

template <size_t sz>
double MyFunc(const Wrapped_t<sz> &f, const std::array<double, sz> &arr1, const std::array<double, sz> &arr2)
{
    // some dummy implementation for demonstratio purposes 
    return f(arr1) + f(arr2);
}

double MyFunc2(const std::array<double, 3> &arr)
{
    // some dummy implementation for demonstratio purposes 
    return std::accumulate(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), 0);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(Wrapped_t<3>) << std::endl;     // 64 bytes for x64 build. You are better off not copying your function object


    std::cout << MyFunc2({ 3.14, 2.18, 2.895 }) << std::endl; // invoking your function as regular

    // to create an std::function object you should use std::bind
    Wrapped_t<3> wrapped = std::bind(&MyFunc2, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::cout << wrapped({ 3.14, 2.18, 2.895 }) << std::endl; // invoking your function wrapped to std::function

    std::array<double, 3> arr1{ 3, 14, 28 },
        arr2{ 2, 18,9 };

    // this is what you asked for
    std::cout << MyFunc(wrapped, arr1, arr2) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you too, I appreciate the performance point of view! :)